# Hook A Private Method In Another App Using Xposed

Tags: android, xposed-framework, xposed

Is it possible to hook a private method in another app using xposed?

I have written this module

```
public void handleLoadPackage(final LoadPackageParam lpparam) throws Throwable {
    if (!lpparam.packageName.equals("com.esealed.dalily"))
        return;


    findAndHookMethod("com.esealed.dalily.i.c",lpparam.classLoader ,"a","com.esealed.dalily.model.VersionInfo", new XC_MethodHook() {
        @Override
        protected void beforeHookedMethod(MethodHookParam param) throws Throwable {
            Log.d("XPOSED_MOD","Inside  a method ");
            param.setResult(null);


        }


    });
```

it dose not throw any error saying the class is not found but when the method is called it dose not write any thing to the log.So I assumed this happens because the method is private but i am not sure.

Comment: Have you tried to use the Xposed logging instead? `XposedBridge.log("xyz");`

Answer (score 1):

According to xposed bridge source (https://github.com/rovo89/XposedBridge/blob/art/app/src/main/java/de/robv/android/xposed/XposedHelpers.java), findAndHookMethod calls getDeclaredMethod and set its result to be accessible. That means the function should work on any method, public or not.

Can you hook a public method of the same class?

Comment: I had an issue hooking private method using `XposedHelpers.findAndHookMethod(...)`. However using `.getDeclaredMethods()` and `XposedBridge.hookMethod(...)` works